# How to get unicode code points in perl v5.24?

Tags: perl, unicode, ord

I want to document the hex unicode code points for strings that are cut and pasted into bash as an argument.  ord does not do this; ord seems to only work within ascii bounds.

Most of what I've found regarding ord, is at least six years old, or older, and no longer relevant, as I am using v5.24 which I've read has unicode support build in.
In python it is trivial:

```
for i in unicode(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8'):
    print i.encode("utf_16_be").encode("hex")
```

which works from bash.
I think the problem is with the ord function itself, which does not seem updated for unicode.

```
# ord.pl does not provide the unicode code point for a pasted variable.
use strict;
use warnings;
#use charnames (); #nope.
#use feature 'unicode_strings'; #nope.  Already automatically using as of v5.12.
#use utf8; #nope.
#binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)"); #nope.

my $arg = "";

foreach $arg  (@ARGV) {
  print $arg . " is " . ord($arg) . " in code.\n";  # seems to me ord is ascii only.
  #utf8::encode($arg);  #nope.
  #print unpack("H*", $arg) . "\n";  #nope.

  #printf "%vX\n", $arg;  #nope.
}
```

which gets:

```
david@A8DT01:~/bin$ ord.pl A B C D a b c d \  \\ … —  €
A is 65 in code.
41
B is 66 in code.
42
C is 67 in code.
43
D is 68 in code.
44
a is 97 in code.
61
b is 98 in code.
62
c is 99 in code.
63
d is 100 in code.
64
  is 32 in code.
20
\ is 92 in code.
5c
… is 226 in code.
c3a2c280c2a6
— is 226 in code.
c3a2c280c294
 is 239 in code.
c3afc280c2a8
€ is 226 in code.
c3a2c282c2ac
david@A8DT01:~/bin$
```

I'd like to get the output I get in python:

```
david@A8DT01:~/bin$ python code-points.py "ABCDabcd \ … —  €"
0041
0042
0043
0044
0061
0062
0063
0064
0020
005c
0020
2026
0020
2014
0020
f028
0020
20ac
david@A8DT01:~/bin$
```

Comment: Try run your script with option `-CSDA` : i.e. `perl -CSDA ord.pl A B C D a b c d \  \\ … —  €`. It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a problem with ord, but with encoding. Input from the commandline will usually be UTF-8 encoded, and ord only takes a single character, not a multi byte string. You can use the `-CA` switch to decode `@ARGV` automatically (or `-CSA` so that STDOUT is also encoded for the terminal), or do it in the script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
  my $decoded = decode 'UTF-8', $arg;
  print $arg . " is " . ord($decoded) . " in code.\n";
}
```

However, your python script is doing something very different, it is returning the hex representation of the string encoded to UTF-16BE, not the decimal ordinals of the unicode characters. You can do this also in Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
  my $utf16 = encode 'UTF-16BE', decode 'UTF-8', $arg;
  print $arg . " is " . sprintf("%vX", $utf16) . " in code.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  As I suspected, ord is not unicode capable.  The non-ord example does return a usable approximation of a keyboard useable code point.  IE: Cntl-U ####.  I'd have to lose the dot, easily enough, were I to use it in reference to common code point parlance.  A two (to four) byte character is still one character, even though it may have more than one byte.  Since ord seems to be limited to a single byte, I call that ascii only, right or wrong.  The docs need to say that, so that a noob like myself doesn't try to use it with unicode.  The docs do not say that currently.

Comment: @DavidWeeks That's not accurate. It is perfectly unicode capable. `ord("\N{SNOWMAN}")` will return the ordinal of the snowman character fine. The problem is you have a misunderstanding of Perl's string model, or the difference between Unicode and character encodings, or both. An encoded string is still just a string of bytes, and needs to be decoded to be used as a string of characters. This is best done at the edges, such as when reading or writing, or via layers on the handles.

Comment: @DavidWeeks Here is an example. I have two strings: "\N{U+2603}" and "\N{U+00E2}\N{U+0098}\N{U+0083}". These strings are both valid series of codepoints and not equal to each other. If you encode the first string to UTF-8, or decode the second one from UTF-8, it will equal the other. The second string is what you get in `@ARGV` without setting `-CA`, or from STDIN without a decoding layer, etc. The first string is what you need to do any operations on it as a single unicode character, such as ord(), length(), regex matches, and so on.

Comment: @DavidWeeks I'll also add that the non-ord example does not in fact print the codepoint, it prints the UTF-16BE encoded bytes, which do not match the codepoint in cases such as `\N{U+20000}` like in @ikegami's example. So your python program will also be wrong in that case. If you want the hex representation of the codepoint, use the first example but with `sprintf('%04X', ord($decoded))`.

Comment: Re "*As I suspected, ord is not unicode capable.*", Completely true and completely false at the same time. `ord` knows nothing of Unicode; it just returns the first character of the string as its number. However, if the first character of the string is a string of Unicode Code Points, then `ord` will happily returns its number.

Comment: Re "*The non-ord example does return a usable approximation of a keyboard useable code point.*", Grinnz's code prints the decimal representation of the number, while that sequence requires the hex representation of the number. I'm not sure why they did that when you asked for hex. You can consult my answer for how to do this.

Comment: @ikegami Only because it was what the original code did. The requirements and the code are of course in opposition, but it seems we got there in the end.

Answer (score 3):

The Perl equivalent of

```
for ucp_str in unicode(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8'):
    print ucp_str.encode("utf_16_be").encode("hex")
```

is

```
use Encode qw( decode encode );

for my $ucp_str (split(//, decode("UTF-8", $ARGV[0]))) {
   say unpack("H*", encode("UTF-16be", $ucp_str));
}
```

Demo:

```
$ ./a.py aé€♠
0061
00e9
20ac
2660
d840dc00

$ ./a.pl aé€♠
0061
00e9
20ac
2660
d840dc00
```

But you asked to output the code points, and that's not what those programs do. For that, you can use the following:

```
use Encode qw( decode_utf8 );

for my $ucp_num (unpack('W*', decode_utf8($ARGV[0]))) {
   say sprintf("%04X", $ucp_num);
}
```

Demo:

```
$ ./a2.pl aé€♠
0061
00E9
20AC
2660
20000
```

---

To get the characters of a string as strings:

- `unpack('(a)*', $_)`
- `split(//, $_)`

To get the characters of a string as numbers:

- `unpack('W*', $_)`
- `map { ord($_) } split(//, $_))`

To convert a string of bytes (characters in range 0x00..0xFF) into hex:

- `unpack('H*', $_)`
- `join "", map { sprintf('%02X', $_) } split(//, $_))`

Easy way to see the characters of a string as hex for debugging:

- `sprintf("%vX", $_)`

Comment: Thank you ikegami.  I got a syntax error from "say" in your examples, until I added  `use v5.24;`  I thought it didn't matter, I was wrong.  Ah, the life of a noob.  This gets me what I set out to do, which is to determine the code point of an unknown pasted character.

Comment: `say` requires `use feature qw( say );` as mentioned in the documentation for `say`. `use v5.24;` includes the functionality of `use feature qw( say );`. We omit the shebang line, `use strict;` (ALWAYS use), `use warnings;` (ALWAYS use) and `use feature qw( say );` (if required) from snippets for brevity.